# Subversion and multiple copies of the same file (text and binary)

Tags: svn, repository, diff, binaryfiles

What Subversion do when a file is copied in multiple folders ? Does it keep a unique copy internally or each copy is duplicated and it controls the diffs for each one ?

And what happen with binary files ? If a library (binary) file is added and commited in multiple folders what Subversion do to optimize its storage in that situation ?

Answer (score 3):

I am using subversion 1.7. With this version, the server stores only a single copy - in both cases:

- Creating copies in the repository (i.e. `svn cp ...`)
- Independently adding files with exactly the same content.

That is true for both storage formats, i.e. *fsfs* and *bdb*.

I have verified it with a simple shell script that created an uncompressible 1 MB file, and added it in both ways 100 times to the repository. At the end, the repository required in all cases less than 3 MB. So there is some overhead, but not the whole content for each copy.

Comment: Thanks by the answer. Nice to know that. But why svn client send the full file over the network if it could just check the hash id that represents the file contents when the file already is in repository ?